# Slow VPN performance - TCP Issue?

Tags: vpn, pcap

I am having issues with the performance of a VPN, it is just one VPN in particular and I have captured the following PCAP from the server in question.

My understanding is that the "Ack" field should be the "Seq" number of the packet it is acknowledging?

If so, does this look bad with multiple Ack's to packet at sequence 1 and would this cause my slow performance potentially?

[image: Wireshark]